# Ошибка "multiple-value in single-value context"

Tags: golang

В коде:

```
fmt.Printf("Число фиббоначи для %v: %v", userNum, Fibbonachi(userNum, true))
```

Функция `Fibbonachi` получает 2 значения (1-е значение - число, второе способ расчета), и возвращает 2 значения (1-е значение - ответ, 2-е значение - ошибка или `nil`).

Получаю ошибку

> multiple-value Fibbonachi(userNum, true) (value of type (int, error)) in single-value context

что логично, но как мне вывести через `Printf` только первое возвращаемое значение без ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ:

```
result, err := Fibbonachi(userNum, true)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Число фиббоначи для %v: %v", userNum, result)
```